# how can I use google product search api?

Tags: python, api, curl, command, google-product-search

I'm a beginner of programming and I have little experience in Python, but it's basic level.

I'm trying to make web application using **Google cloud vision product search API**.

I tried to follow how-to-guides on google, but I totally can't understand [Creating a product set section](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/create-product-set#vision-product-search-create-prod-set-drest).

First I tried to use codes in python category, but I can't understand how it works.

It also shows command like

> HTTP method and URL:
>
> `POST https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/locations/location-id/productSets`
>
> Request JSON body:
>
> ```
> {
>   "displayName": "display-name"
> }
> ```

I tried this in Cloud Shell, but it doesn't work.

I don't know where and how to input those command at all.

Please answer how to use those commands.
Thank you.

Comment: You might want to see `Requests` library if you are doing it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an example like this (replace with your project and desired location)

```
curl -s -d "{ display_name: 'your display name' }" "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/projects/your_project/locations/us-west1/productSets?product_set_id=your_set_id" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)";
```